# webpack starts complaining of module not found when copied source to another machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I need to run a piece of code that running fine on my box on a different machine. I just checked out the same code on different machine and did

```
npm install
npm start
```

the same set of commands works fine on my local box, but on second machine i start getting

```
ERROR in ./src/client/routes.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/editor-components/Editor' 
in '/home/app/my-project/src/client'
@ ./src/client/routes.jsx 26:14-62
@ ./src/client/app.jsx
```

Here is my directory structure

```
 ├── client
 │   ├── actions
 │   │   └── index.jsx
 │   ├── app.jsx
 │   ├── camsServer.jsx
 │   ├── components
 │   │   ├── editor-components
 │   │   │   ├── container.jsx
 │   │   │   ├── containerheader.jsx
 │   │   │   ├── details-component.jsx
 │   │   │   ├── editor.jsx
 │   │   │   ├── jsoneditor-components
 │   │   │   ├── modals
 │   │   │   ├── template-components
 │   │   │   ├── variants.jsx
 │   │   │   └── version-history-components
 │   │   ├── logout.jsx
 │   │   ├── main.jsx
 │   │   ├── navbar.jsx
 │   │   ├── templateSearch.jsx
 │   │   └── userInputSearch.jsx
 │   ├── images
 │   │   └── electrode.png
 │   ├── reducers
 │   │   └── index.jsx
 │   ├── routes.jsx
 │   ├── styles
 │   │   ├── base.css
 │   │   ├── button.css
 │   │   ├── details.css
 │   │   ├── editor.css
 │   │   ├── jsoneditor.css
 │   │   ├── loader.css
 │   │   ├── logout.css
 │   │   ├── modal-push.css
 │   │   ├── modal.css
 │   │   ├── template.css
 │   │   ├── templateSearch.css
 │   │   ├── variants.css
 │   │   ├── version-history.css
 │   │   └── wrapped.css
 │   └── sw-registration.js
 └── server
     ├── index.js
     ├── plugins
     │   ├── pwa.js
     │   └── token
     │       └── index.js
     └── views
         └── index-view.js
```

Any idea what is it that i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
npm i
```

To pull all your package

Then

```
npm build
```

Comment: I think ,its  enough to import  your package.json. So i think problem is in your File "routes.jsx"

Comment: Or check your package.json, compare with your package.json and see whichs package missing :)

Answer (score 0):

Found my silly mistake..

./components/editor-components/Editor should have been ./components/editor-components/editor

Wonder how is it able to resolve on my macbook.